# Would this be an invalid or valid argument?

Tags: logic, argumentation

All mathematical truths are knowable.
All mathematical truths are eternal. 
So All that is knowable is eternal.

Comment: We do not answer HW questions for people. We can help, but please explain why you are having difficulty with this example.

Comment: Here is a Wikipedia page that might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism This looks like "figure 3". All of the sentences are universal affirmative. Try replacing the terms with something else to see if the form works for them as well or not.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong. Following the sylogism: All mathematical truths are knowable, and all mathematical truths are eternal; so all mathematical truths are both knowable and eternal — those are two qualities of 'all mathematical truths', and so far that's all they are. There is nothing that implies that 'all that is knowable is eternal' or that 'all that is eternal is knowable'.

See the following diagram:

[image]

We, therefore, conclude that there is a group called the eternals and a group called the knowables. There are things that are only knowables, and things that are only eternals, but then there are things that are both. Among those things that are both, you have 'all mathematical truths'. So we have to keep in mind that:

1. There **might be** things that are both knowable and eternal, but that are **not** mathematical truths.
2. There are things that are only eternal, and not knowable.
3. There are things that are only knowable, not eternal.
4. Mathematical truths are both knowable and eternal, but that doesn't imply a link between all things that are eternal and all things that are knowable.

Comment: You wrote an Euler diagram NOT a Venn DIAGRAM.   There are differences between the two types of diagrams.

Comment: @Logikal Thanks for the input, I did a quick search and I interpreted that Venn’s are Euler’s that show all possible relations. To me, the diagram I drew shows all possible relations. So wouldn’t it be a Venn nevertheless?

Comment: No you are wrong. EULER and VENN diagrams are distinct.   One is not a type of the other.  One is used by math and the other by philosophy.  Venn diagrams are distinct by always showing  three interloping circles. One for the subject, one for the predicate & the other for the middle term for an argument.  There are never circles within circles.  Circles within circles exclusively means Euler diagrams nothing else. Math diagrams do not show all possible outcomes.  It was meant to show set membership. Logic is not the same as math. People try to pretend it's all the same . There are distinctions

Comment: @Logikal Everywhere I go, your claim is contradicted. Can you add credible sources to that? Or maybe even do your own self-answered question in this SE?

Comment: Try any logic book written by a philosopher  not a mathematician.   Where did you look? Show me the links and I think you misread them. EULER was a mathematician. VENN DIAGRAMS are named after JOHN VENN. THEY ARE THREE circles. No Venn diagrams have circles within circles. Euler diagrams are for set theory. VENN diagrams are for argument validly. Two different purposes by two distinct fields. Where are you looking? Do you know what contradiction mean?  Something is off.

Comment: You can look at any of Patrick Hurley logic texts. There he uses Venn diagrams so you can see there are always three distinct circles that overlap. You can also look up Irvin copies logic texts.  Same methods.  I dont know what you saw. Care to share?

Comment: @Logikal I have changed the answer to just say "diagram", as I dislike being incorrect, as any sensible person. However, if you would like me to learn the *proper* difference and then include it in the answer, please provide *proper* sources. I won't go around the internet looking for Hurley's "texts" only for a petty nitpick.

Comment: Perhaps you should give YOUR sources for someone saying circles within circles are Venn diagrams. Venn diagrams are distinct by three circles. The picture never changes whereas the Euler diagram does such as when the circle is not in a larger circle. You can Google images of this. It is not that hard. Also I mentioned Hurley but you can look up Irving Copi as well. It is not like just TWO philosophy logic books in the universe. You did not look hard or you were looking OUTSIDE of philosophy.

Comment: @Logikal I don't want to because I don't care; as I said, it is a minor thing. And as I said, I did search for it and didn't find anything that confirmed what you said particularly; granted, I did not look hard, but as I said, I don't really care. If you are passionate about it enough, which I respect, give me one link (of proper source), just one, and I will look into it; but what I don't respect is your crude tone, which might be related to the overall reception of your submissions to this stackexchange.

Comment: @Logikal Care to explain your downvote, mate? Mainly after I corrected it to only say 'diagram'?

Comment: @William, take Logikal’s writing with a pinch of salt. They have consistently attempted on this site to push an anti-mathematical agenda with very poor substantive backing to their position.

Answer (score 1):

False, because not all truths are mathematical.